# Проблема с библиотекой TensorFlow В NetBeans IDE Java

Tags: java, netbeans, lib, tensorflow

```
run:
Process was cancelled by user.
Opening: C:\Users\payan\Downloads\inception_dec_2015
Image Path: C:\Users\payan\Downloads\maruti-suzuki-baleno.jpg
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: windows, architecture: x86_64. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java/README.md for possible solutions (such as building the library from source). Additional information on attempts to find the native library can be obtained by adding org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1 to the system properties of the JVM.
    at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:77)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:70)
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.<clinit>(Tensor.java:791)
    at com.emaraic.ObjectRecognition.Recognizer.actionPerformed(Recognizer.java:152)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Пробывал много чего !Но установка библиотек с github не помогает!!
Файла на официальном сайте нету!

Параметры IDE:

```
 ls=~/jni
    file=~/jni/*
    -Djava.library.path=./jni
    build.compiler.emacs=true
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался надо было в папку с проектом закинуть нативную библиотеку отсюда [Tensorflow JNI lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/libtensorflow_jni)